# javascript is closing my HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am adding a table to a page in javascript using.

```
$("#tablediv").append("<table border = '1'><tbody><tr><td width='100px'><b>Result</b></td><td width='100px'><b>Binding</b></td><td width='744px'><b>Value</b></td></tr>");
```

The problem is that what it is run `</tbody>` and `</table>` is getting added at the end.

How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot add an incomplete element to the DOM tree. I think jQuery is creating the elements accordingly even though your HTML is broken.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why would you not want to close the table tag?

Comment: There is no reason to want to insert incomplete HTML into the DOM. If you do (as you are trying to), and then inspect it via a DOM inspector, they will probably show you the correct HTML - in your case, with tags closed. If you want to do further operations on the HTML before closing the tags, do this away from the DOM then insert everything only once ready.

Comment: I am creating a table from xml so as I am parsing it and I creating each element in the table as it does so using .append

Comment: ok so Im best off putting everything into a var then printing it all at once. makes sense.

Comment: You can just create the table and append elements to it (`$('#tablediv table').append( ... )`). There's no reason to keep it "open".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to **add new elements** to the table after you create it?

*ID* your table and then append to that.

```
$("#tablediv")
  .append("<table id='mytable' border = '1'><tbody><tr><td width='100px'><b>Result</b></td><td width='100px'><b>Binding</b></td><td width='744px'><b>Value</b></td></tr></table>");​​​

$("#mytable")
  .append("<tr><td>Bla</td><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>");
```

Call the *second* jQuery function **each time** you want to **add a new row** to your table.

Comment: for performance sake it's better to append to a var rather than invoke jQuery for each element

Answer (score 1):

I'm under the impression you want this so you can loop through outputting your results?

```
var table = "<table border = '1'><tbody><tr><td width='100px'><b>Result</b></td><td width='100px'><b>Binding</b></td><td width='744px'><b>Value</b></td></tr>";
// loop through your data here
table += "</tbody></table>";

 document.getElementById("tablediv").innerHTML += table;
```

Comment: Firefox and chrome will still add the closing tags. Cant say that about IE

Comment: Notice how the table isn't being added to the DOM until after the table has finished being created. I believe this is what the man wants (So he can loop through his results, adding them to the table as he goes)

Answer (score 1):

create var, append your stuff to it and then when you're ready call .append(html)

```
var html = "";
html += "<table border = '1'><tbody><tr><td width='100px'><b>Result</b></td><td width='100px'><b>Binding</b></td><td width='744px'><b>Value</b></td></tr>"
$("#tablediv").append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You are operating on a DOM, not a stream of HTML.

jQuery allows you to use HTML syntax to describe a DOM fragment to be created (which you can then insert or otherwise manipulate), but that is just for convenience. If the HTML isn't a valid fragment, it will be error corrected.

If you want to deal in pieces of HTML, you have to do so as strings, not jQuery objects